# Need to pull results on page load with google maps API

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I need to display results (bar and shops based on the current location) on page load. It currently works if I submit the form but I am trying to make it work on page load.

I am trying with the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $.post("<?= site_url('stockists/search'); ?>", {location: coords});
  });
```

coords is a variable containing the current location

Comment: is `coords` defined at that point? You may need to run your geolocation process at page load, and when that ends, run your mapping step

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on a local machine, your browser may be blocking it (check the console).
If not, try putting it in a slight delay...

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.post("<?= site_url('stockists/search'); ?>", {location: coords});
},500);
```